# Using setter injection for sub classes extra dependencies

Tags: php, oop

For an example let's say you have:

```
abstract class AbstractA {

    private $dependency1;
    private $dependency2;
    private $dependency3;

    public function __construct(One $dep1, Two $dep2, Three $dep3) {
        // Set the class properties...
    }

}
```

Now we have a class `B`:

```
class B extends AbstractA {

    private $dependency4;
    private $dependency5;

    public function __construct(One $dep1, Two $dep2, Three $dep3, Four $dep4, Five $dep5) {
        parent::__construct($dep1, $dep2, $dep3);
        $this->dependency4 = $dep4;
        $this->dependency5 = $dep5;
    }

}
```

What if we have classes `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` all the way up to `Z` which are child/sub classes of `AbstractA` and have one or more extra dependencies than `AbstractA`. What if you want to change the order of the dependencies in the `AbstractA` class for some reason or to remove one of them, you would now have to edit the constructor in classes `B` all the way to `Z` which would take a long time.

I was thinking what if you used setter injection to inject any extra dependencies the sub classes may need so therefore you don't need to continuously add the constructor into the sub classes so making a change in the abstract classes dependencies does not take 3 hours.

```
class B extends AbstractA {

    private $dependency4;
    private $dependency5;

    // No constructor so the parent one gets executed.

   public function setDependency4(......

   public function setDependency5(......

}
```

I know in order to use this class you would have to remember to inject to extra dependencies after the object is instantiated which is extra work but it may save time in the long run.

Is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: You should favor composition over inheritance =P Usually, if your class has such amount of dependencies, it is considered to be a code smell. You also should think on fact that your "dependencies" might not be **mandatory** for instance's functionality. Instead these "dependencies" are actually just acted upon by some of the methods. Therefore, you could just pass them in the methods as required, instead of using class's local variables.

Comment: Okay thanks. I do use lots of interfaces but I sometimes end up doing inheritance.

Comment: You should use a library to manage the dependencies like https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn rather than trying to do it all through setters.

Comment: @Danack I do use one but I think you are misunderstanding my question. It's okay now though.

Comment: worth reading : http://r.je/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection.html